# "systematize" vs. "systemize"

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

Merriam-Webster defines ["systemize"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systemize) as an alternate spelling of ["systematize."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systematize) Is there any reason to choose one over the the other (besides "systematize" sounding a little weird to my ears)?

I did notice that the spell checker in my browser is marking "systemize" as incorrect, though Word says it's fine (U.S. English).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think "systemize" is uncommon enough to lead you to prefer "systematize" — and "just sounds weird" is often a good enough reason all by itself.

Comment: In truth, both versions sound a little weird to me. Perhaps that's reason enough to go with some form of "X makes Y systematic" instead.

Comment: It'll be a matter of personal taste.  To me, "systemize" sounds weird :-)

Comment: I think both have an air of "management-speak" buzzwords anyway. I'd rather see *organise*, *categorise*, *classify*, etc. in most contexts.

Comment: There's also the medical usage of *systemize*, the aspect of something with respect to the whole (human) body (i.e., 'system'). *cf*. 'systemic'.

Answer (score 4):

The word "system" is derived from Greek. In declension of some Greek words the word stem is longer than the simplest form; in this case the simplest form is "systema", but the stem is "systemat-". Analogously, thema and schema are declensed "themat-" and "schemat", respectively. In derivations the stem is usually used, e.g. systematic, schematic.

In my ears then, "systemize" sounds as weird as "themize" or "schemize" would. That is, they sound as if something is lacking.
But this is probably only the case with those that were tought the classical languages in school.

Comment: "Systemize" sounds weird to me, despite my ignorance of Greek.  I think the reason it sounds weird might be that I don't think I've ever heard or read it before, whereas I've certainly read "systematize".

Answer (score 1):

The NOAD reports *systemize* is "another term for systematize." That is all the description given by the NOAD; I guess that means *systemize* is not so often used.

Comment: systematize gets about 4 times as many hits on Google

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, **systemize** is a neologism born in business environments where such things are common. 
Business - and to a lesser degree economics in general - is one of the fields where, or perhaps *the field par excellence* where neologisms are coined more often than expressions already in use are employed.
**Systemize** would sound negative in a philosophical context.

**Systematize** means *both* "*to build/draw a system from/out of something*" and "*to apply systematic laws on something under constraints of consistency and final efficiency*". 
I underline *the definitions I give are mine* and *I am no authority of any kind in this matter.*
A complete definition of **systematize** would be "*to identify the laws OR rules it **works by** and define them collectively as an organism, to be abstracted and treated as a model of rules of interaction between the given variables, as defined by their hierachy*."

*Hierarchy of variables* is nothing more than an expression I coined myself and I have no clue whether it has ever been previously spoken of and under which definition.
I employ the term **model** as it is employed in economics and game theory. 
The definition I gave is pretty circular in my own eyes, but when it comes to semantics applied to define logistics I cannot honestly do any better.

Perhaps it may be useful to notice here that, in Italian, **sistemizzare** [literally **to systemize**] means "*to quickly and cheaply make something safe and well working, weeding out 'noise' or errors*", "*to clean up a set of notions or actions*". 
**Sistemare** [literally **to system** (!)] instead means "*to tidy up*", "*to settle*". 
**Sistematizzare**, literally **to systematize**, only means "*to make something work like a system, like an organism*", implying that the something was not originally supposed to be able to do it and it cannot happen without human work.
The only word among these three that refers to something **supposed to be** a system is **sistemare**.

I would draw the conclusion that **systemize** is, in philosophy et caetera, the "parody" (*so to say of course!*) of **systematize**, a "should-have-been systematizing". 
In business and management environments instead, it is used to define the subordination of a shapeless mass of stuff to a set of pre-existing rules, in order to make it comply with an external system it must be blended into. 
This system may or may not be the one and the same with the set of rules.

As in all derivational languages, prefixes and suffixes are the key divide (term no one could tell me the English translation of, and that I eventually found on an The Economist title page - "The Gay Divide", last October. In Italian we say "il discrimine", literally translated as "the discriminant").

Another hint from Italian adjectives: **sistematico** means "*constantly happening under given conditions*", and it is often used to mean the exact opposite - "*all else variable, this stubbornly keeps happening*" because of the Italian ethos of implying anything and everything, including contradictions. In the earlier case, the system we are referring to is the *small world* the something is a cell of - in the latter case, it is the *big world* that spans the barriers of local conditions and imposes its external dominant laws.
**Sistemico** is instead a word only used by physicians. It means that a process is found to be happening throughout the whole body, the whole **system**, and is not generated by a local phenomenon.

As you see, the semantics behind these terms are all completely different. It must be that **system** is such an episteme in itself that it works as a root morph, declined to apply to minor "local" epistemes.

English goes by ear. What it sounds like is what it is like.
I cannot add anything more.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - Google trends of the usage of both words: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=systemize,systematize

Comment: That's one way to start. But do explain what you observe from the trends, instead of merely linking to it. A better tool would be Ngrams. https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: Via google ngrams https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=systemization%2Csystematization%2Csystemize%2Csystematize&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 I see that the nouns systematization and systemization are more common than the verbs. Thanks for bringing up ngrams, @NVZ

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the lexicologists would argue about it but I see *systematize* as 'making something systematic' and *systemize* as creating a *system* from something. They are certainly not the same thing.

The [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/systematize) defines **systematize** as:

> arrange according to an organized system; make systematic

implying that an existing system is followed in arranging something.

In contrast, the [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/systematize) quotes the AHD thus:

> To formulate into or reduce to a system

*Usage examples*:
Progress in Brain Research (Elsevier) [p.170](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=JFpq6hYQRhQC&pg=PA170&dq=%22systemize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=61LuUrDXM4eVrAe_wYDgAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22systemize%22&f=false)

> Systemizing is the drive to analyze or construct systems. These might be any kind of system(s). What defines a system is that it follows rules, and when we **systemize** we are trying to identify the rules that govern the system, in order to predict how that system will behave (Baron-Cohen, 2006). [emphasis mine]

Fuchs, et al., (Ed.), *Internet and Surveillance* [p.139](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=K3xzhq5UulEC&pg=PA139&dq=%22systemize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=61LuUrDXM4eVrAe_wYDgAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22systemize%22&f=false)

> The overall aim of this chapter was to clarify how we theorize and **systemize** Internet surveillance in the modern economy. The chapter constructed theoretically founded typologies in order to **systemize** the existing literature of Internet surveillance studies and to analyze examples of surveillance.

I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

We should generally prefer shorter, more essential expressions of an idea and/or concept when using language to avoid ambiguity, and "dead weight."

And we should subordinate arbitrary personal preferences to the purpose of language: precision, communication, essentialism.

Therefore, adding the two letters "at" between "system" and "ize" is completely useless. We should say "systemize."

Answer (score -1):

http://www.quora.com/Are-both-systematize-and-systemize-proper-words

Just saw this online. Hope this also helps because I also have the same problem.

Comment: Please summarize the explanation, in addition to providing a link to it.